# Cheap USB keypad with media keys or programmable USB buttons

Tags: usb, keyboards

I'd like to get a separate small USB device that I can use to control my media player. Basically if it could send standard media keys, it would be good. It would stand on my desk, next to my keyboard which does not have media keys but which I otherwise like. Also, I don't want to spend a fortune on it - let's say, 20€ max. My OS is Windows 10.

Some options that would work:

- An explicit USB "media keypad" (haven't found anything like that)
- A standard USB keypad with programmable keys
- A USB device with at least 5 buttons which are programmable
- Infrared/radio remote control

What does not work:

- Adding a standard numeric USB keyboard and remapping the keys in software. I still want the numeric keypad on my main keyboard to work as intended and on Windows it's impossible to remap the keys on a specific keyboard.
- Making a software using [Interception](https://github.com/oblitum/Interception). That's what I'm using now, but it often glitches, to the point where sometimes my main keyboard is getting disabled entirely.

Answer (score 2):

This [mini wireless keyboard](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B00Z81U3YY/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_QGIfEbJWNAEHX) is what I use. Its very cheep and lets me walk away from the computer. It has media buttons and requires no software.

All dedicated media controllers that I know of are much more expensive. Example: [Stream Deck](https://smile.amazon.com/Elgato-Stream-Deck-Controller-customizable/dp/B06XKNZT1P/ref=sr_1_19?keywords=media+control+pc&qid=1578510828&sr=8-19)

Comment: That last one has an LCD display for every key. That's some overkill! But the mini keyboard looks nice, thanks! :) Still would be nice if there was something even more compact. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to tinkering?

DIY boards like the [Arduino Leonardo](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Arduino_BoardLeonardo) have processors with native USB support.
You could hook up your own buttons and program it however you'd like.

Comment: I was thinking about that too, but a quick browse through a local electronics webshop didn't yield any interesting keyboards. But it's still an open idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase programmable macro keypads, but they're typically more than 20€. The one I've linked below is about 33.42€ after clipping the 8% off coupon, but before taxes.

[https://www.amazon.com/Koolertron-Mechanical-Keyboard-One-Handed-Programmable/dp/B07VWHS9V6/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VWHS9V6)

Comment: Yeah, because of the mechanical keys and the RGB backlights. Seriously, I don't need that. But then I guess it's such a niche product that they probably can't afford to make it cheaply. :P

Comment: You would be correct, it is a very niche product so you won't find many options, if any, price lower than that. Funny enough, the mainstream version of these is the Elgato Stream Deck which is exponentially more.